# SCRIPT5009: 'String' is undefined IE9

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-9, undefined

I use jquery-1.7.2.min.js

I have following javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $("#del_category").click(function() {
        if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this category?')) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "someurl",
                datatype: "json",
                csd: window.parent.CSD,
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data.isSuccess) {
                        if (data.isFree) {
                            // error appears if this function invokes
                            this.csd.Popup.currentWindow.hideDialog();
                        } else {
                            alert("Category uses in some FAQ.");
                        }
                    } else {
                        alert("Error. Category was not deleted.");
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        return false;
    });
});
```

It works fine in all browsers except IE9. In IE9 it works correctly (all functions invoked) but shows js error: SCRIPT5009: 'String' is undefined

How I can fix this?

**EDIT**:

This script works without errors:

```
$(function() {
    $("#del_category").click(function() {
        window.parent.CSD.Popup.currentWindow.hideDialog();
    });
});
```

Error appears only in ajax OnSuccess event handler.

Comment: There are no references to `String` in the code you've shown. Can you give us the specific line of code causing the error?

Comment: fiddle or live site ??

Comment: It appears in jquery-1.7.2.js in 509 line:

type: function( obj ) {
  return obj == null ? String( obj ) : class2type[oString.call(obj)] || "object";
},

Comment: As this is executing correctly but you are only getting an error in IE, could this be caused by a typo? I believe `datatype` should be `dataType`?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the `hideDialog();` inside a `setTimeout`. I believe the error is coming up because the dialog is being disposed before jQuery is done with it.

```
$(function() {
    $("#del_category").click(function() {
        if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this category?')) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "someurl",
                datatype: "json",
                csd: window.parent.CSD,
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data.isSuccess) {
                        if (data.isFree) {
                            // error appears if this function invokes
                            var csd = this.csd;
                            setTimeout(function() {
                                csd.Popup.currentWindow.hideDialog();
                            }, 0);
                        } else {
                            alert("Category uses in some FAQ.");
                        }
                    } else {
                        alert("Error. Category was not deleted.");
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        return false;
    });
});
```